# Getting selected dropdown value using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi I have dojo based website which does not support Jqquery. So I need a javascript code to get the selected value text from the dropdown . Can anyone give me plain javascript code?

Comment: What if you ask that directly to Google? xD

Answer (score 1):

It's not that difficult, you could try to do it by yourself.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('select');

function getVal(){
  console.log(sel.value);
}
```

```html
<select id='select'>
<option value='one'>one</option>
<option value='two'>two</option>
<option value='three'>three</option>
</select>
<button onclick='getVal()'>Get value</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just started to lean javascript

Comment: @pradeep And accept it as best answer! :)